# How to launch GUI application on device plugin?

Tags: scripts, systemd, scanner, udev, wacom

How can I automatically launch a GUI program so that it remains open when a device plugs into Ubuntu 16.04?

My goal is to have the program gnome-pie launch when my Cintiq monitor is turned on, and then to have that program terminate when the monitor is turned off.

I have tried working with udev coupled with systemd to call a script that would then launch the program. The script runs but the application doesn't.

Here is my udev line:

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{product}=="DTK-2100", ATTR{idProduct}=="00cc", ATTR{idVendor}=="056a", TAG+="systemd"
```

...and my systemd file contents.

```
[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
ExecStart=/bin/sh /home/user/xsetwacom.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
WantedBy=sys-devices-pci0000:00-0000:00:1a.2-usb5-5\\x2d2.device
```

Lastly here is my script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 4


export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/user/.Xauthority
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 21UX2 Pad pad" Button 1 key Shift ctrl l
xsetwacom set "Wacom Cintiq 21UX2 Pad pad" Button 14 key Shift ctrl r
/home/user/touch-toggle1_ubuntu.sh
gnome-pie & disown
```

Everything except 'gnome-pie & disown' runs correctly and I am not sure why.

Can someone help me solve this? The possibilies that I would like to utilize this behavior goes to usb drives, cameras, scanners, webcams, and pretty much any other thing that requires some sort of GUI interaction.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I was correct in the way I was trying to handle the problem. Unfortunately, I discovered that while I can launch most programs, gnome-pie is not one of them.

Also I learned that sometimes this method will bug out and not work correctly if there is constant disconnecting/reconnecting, even with applications that will launch.

Considering no one else will use gnome-pie this way, finding a solution to getting it working is probably not happening.

Hopefully the Wacom driver for linux will be updated to include a radial menu in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Udev is not prepared for such uses like GUI tools ... It is a low level daemon.

Currently, best solution is to write a script (ex. `python` & `pyudev`) that watches udev events to launch whatever you want.